# How to populate a database using entity framework

Tags: database, vb.net, entity-framework-4, insert

When you use the feature "generate database from model" how do you put some data into a table?

for example i want a tabel with all country after the database is created.

Is there a script / shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have following options

- write a program to create db/table and
  insert data
- create SQL script to create db/table and
  insert data
- use the database management tool
  (e.g. Management Studio for SQL
  Server) to create db/table and insert
  data

Comment: So There is no way to do this by using some feature hidden in the EF ?

Comment: @DVD Prd You looking for something like this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/09/10/model-first.aspx

Comment: @DVD or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx

Comment: Accepted this as the answer + added my solution to the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [Seed()](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/seeding-a-database-with-ef4-code-first/) method?

Answer (score 1):

Accepted Ajay_Whiz answer since it helped me the most i created a bat file that just executes the contex.sql and then some other *.sql files to populate the database.

**Disclaimer this is for development database do not ever ever use this on you productions database. unless you know what your doing**

The generated contex.edmx.sql by Entity framework drops all your data!!!

```
::Automated databasecreater
@echo off
echo createing database
SQLCMD -S. -E -iContext.edmx.sql -e -b
echo add gemeentes
SQLCMD -S. -E -iContainsDataOfTableX.sql -b
pause
```